# Accessing deeply nested dictionary and array values in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a super-nested set of dictionaries and arrays

> var lines = ["set0":["lines":["Line one","Line two"],"pickone": ["set1":"Apples","set2":"Oranges"]],"set1":["lines":["Line one","Line two"],"pickone":["set3":"Bananas","set4":"Grapefruits"]]]

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to make the structure of those nested dictionaries more readable
2. How can I access the values of the nested arrays

For instance, in a Playground I'm trying the following code:

```
lines["set0"]!["lines"]
```

but I'm not getting any result at all.

Comment: `lines["set0"]!["lines"]` worked fine on a playground for me.

Comment: Your example [works](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/0eaf6728-bd65-4b27-8021-7046aa7f52dd/39920c227c89305f/res/a795f670-4fba-4f6b-8ef5-2a8afe13a846/skitch.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to making it readable try:

```
var lines = [
    "set0":[
        "lines":[
            "Line one",
            "Line two"
        ],
        "pickone":[
            "set1":"Apples",
            "set2":"Oranges"
        ]
    ],
    "set1":[
        "lines":[
            "Line one",
            "Line two"
        ],
        "pickone":[
            "set3":"Bananas",
            "set4":"Grapefruits"
        ]
    ]
]
```

And as to your line:

```
lines["set0"]!["lines"]
```

I can confirm that it is working. Maybe you should give playground some time to display the result. Or, possibly, you forgot to:

```
import Foundation
```

Comment: yes, after double-checking i can confirm that it works) thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Andriy Hi, am also facing the same issue in swift 4.2. I can't able to do that. Can you please add the code for the same issue in swift4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question 2: 
after a little change in your code, you can traverse all of it's branches.

```
var lines:AnyObject = ["set0":["lines":["Line one","Line two"],"pickone": ["set1":"Apples","set2":"Oranges"]],"set1":["lines":["Line one","Line two"],"pickone":["set3":"Bananas","set4":"Grapefruits"]]]

    NSLog("original object:\(lines)")
    NSLog("all keys array:\(lines.allKeys)")


    if(lines.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){
        for key  in lines.allKeys{
            var innerDictionary:AnyObject! = lines.valueForKey(key as! NSString as String)
            //NSLog("inner dictionary:\(innerDictionary)")
            NSLog("depth2 keys array:\(innerDictionary.allKeys)")
            if(innerDictionary.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){

                for innerKey  in innerDictionary.allKeys{
                    var innerValue:AnyObject! = innerDictionary.valueForKey(innerKey as! NSString as String)

                    if(innerValue.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){
                        NSLog("Depth3 keys array:\(innerValue.allKeys)")
                        var mostInnerDicionary:AnyObject! = innerDictionary.valueForKey(innerKey as! NSString as String)
                        NSLog("most inner Dictionary:\(mostInnerDicionary)")
                        for mostInnerKey  in mostInnerDicionary.allKeys{
                        var mostInnerValue:AnyObject! = mostInnerDicionary.valueForKey(mostInnerKey as! NSString as String)
                            NSLog("most inner Value:\(mostInnerValue)")
                        }

                    }else{
                       NSLog("innerValue:\(innerValue)")
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

output: run and check the output in console log